# How to update xserver to 1.19?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, xserver

I currently have xserver 1.18.4 installed on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS which I believe causes terrible screen tearing issues on my laptop.

I have tried building xserver 1.19.1 from sources using this repo https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server but without success.

Is there something I'm missing here? Should I maybe update my kernel version or something?

Comment: @Pilot6 well it helped to fix tearing! After so many hours...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to build anything from source. Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

and you will have the 1.19 xserver version.

Comment: Thanks! Actually xserver 1.19 has PRIME Synchronization support which fixed my tearing. All I needed to do after updating xserver was [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/957814/linux/prime-and-prime-synchronization/post/5190735/#5190735).