# Poor GNOME performance with Intel integrated GPU on Ubuntu 16.04 (Intel HD530 / 4K)

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, performance, xserver, 4k-monitor

I have a really poor performance in my GNOME Desktop with my Intel HD 530 integrated GPU. On my 4k Screen, everything is unsmooth. Websites with a lot of Javascript load slow and are kind of unresponsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution for me: [How to update xserver to 1.19?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947084/how-to-update-xserver-to-1-19)

Install current X-Server version with:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

You can see the version of your current X-Server with:

```
sudo X -version
```